# TypeError: Order.find is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, postman

I am building ecommerce website using MERN stack. And I am getting error while testing using Postman.

backend/controllers/user.js

```
const User = require("../models/user");
const Order = require("../models/order");

exports.userPurchaseList = (req, res) => {
  Order.find({ user: req.profile._id })
    .populate("user", "_id name")
    .exec((err, order) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          error: "No Order in this account",
        });
      }
      return res.json(order);
    });
};
```

backend/models/Order.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema;

const ProductCartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  product: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: "Product",
  },
  name: String,
  count: Number,
  price: Number,
});

const ProductCart = mongoose.model("ProductCart", ProductCartSchema);

const OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    products: [ProductCartSchema],
    transaction_id: {},
    amount: { type: Number },
    address: String,
    status: {
      type: String,
      default: "Recieved",
      enum: ["Cancelled", "Delivered", "Shipped", "Processing", "Recieved"],
    },
    updated: Date,
    user: {
      type: ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const Order = mongoose.model("Order", OrderSchema);

module.exports = { Order, ProductCart };
```

backend/models/User.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const uuidv1 = require("uuid/v1");

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      maxlength: 32,
      trim: true,
    },
    lastname: {
      type: String,
      maxlength: 32,
      trim: true,
      // required: false,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    userinfo: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
    },
    encry_password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    salt: String,
    role: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    purchases: {
      type: Array,
      default: [],
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

backend/routes/user.js

```
router.get(
  "/orders/user/:userId",
  isSignedIn,
  isAuthenticated,
  userPurchaseList
);
```

Error:-
TypeError: Order.find is not a function
at exports.userPurchaseList (C:\Users\Rahul\MernBootcamp\projbackend\controllers\user.js:47:9)

TESTING this route using POSTMAN.

Comment: Naming shouldn't be a problem. Because I have followed this same naming convention in all other models and I'm not facing any issues with them, except this one. Thanks

Comment: The problem with this error can often be found with just a little debugging.  A `console.log('Order')` would probably have allowed you to find the issue quickly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have exported an object so in your *backend/controllers/user.js*

you could import it like so from destructuring from the object then the rest of your code would be okay

```
const {Order} = require("../models/order");
```

**or**
accessing it using the dot notation
when calling the find Function
//importing it at the top

```
const Order = require("../models/order");

exports.userPurchaseList = (req, res) => {
  Order.Order.find({ user: req.profile._id })
    .populate("user", "_id name")
    .exec((err, order) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          error: "No Order in this account",
        });
      }
      return res.json(order);
    });
};
```